# Determining if a point is inside a polygon?

Tags: java, polygon

So I got this algorithm from here.

http://www.ytechie.com/2009/08/determine-if-a-point-is-contained-within-a-polygon/

```
private List<Point> points;
@Override
public boolean contains(Point aPoint) {

            int j = points.size() - 1;
            boolean oddNodes = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
            {
                if (points.get(i).getY() < aPoint.getY() && points.get(j).getY() >= aPoint.getY() ||
                    points.get(j).getY() < aPoint.getY() && points.get(i).getY() >= aPoint.getY());
                {
                    if (points.get(i).getX() +
                        (aPoint.getY() - points.get(i).getY())/(points.get(j).getY() - points.get(j).getY()) * (points.get(j).getX() - points.get(i).getX()) < aPoint.getX())

                    {
                        oddNodes = !oddNodes;
                    }
                }
                j = i;
            }

            return oddNodes;

        }
```

The algorithm was not in java, but I converted it, but it does not seem to be working. Its failing the following test case.

My polygon consists of three points. (1,1), (99,99), (199,1), and the test is (0,0) this should return false as it is not in the polygon, but it returns true despite using that algorithm. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Please see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26519/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-near-or-inside-polygon)

Comment: Extraneous semicolon at end of first if-statement